# How do I use the Return statement in this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript

How do I use return statement in this code? I want to be able to use the value anytime: Is it possible?

```
function oddNumberZ(){
    oddNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13]

    for(i = 0; i < oddNumber.length; i++){
        if(i % 2 !== 0){
            console.log(i)   
        } 
    }
}             

console.log(oddNumberZ())
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Please revise to describe your goals in more detail.

Comment: what do you want the function to return? you are printing to the console already in the function

Comment: As @isherwood says, what are you trying to do?  Do you want oddNumberZ() to return an array of the odd numbers??

Comment: `return {value to return};`?

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+filter+odd+numbers+in+array) of [Javascript How to return an array with odd numbers](/q/45570965/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

This will log `undefined` because `oddNumberZ()` doesn't return anything.

If you want to return an array of odd numbers you can populate something to return, like

```js
function oddNumberZ(){
    const oddNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13]
    const results = [];
    for(i = 0; i < oddNumber.length; i++)
        if(i % 2 !== 0) 
            results.push(i)   
        
    return results;
}
```

Alternatively JS also supports generator functions that let you yield return in the loop:

```js
function* oddNumberZ(){
    const oddNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13]
    for(i = 0; i < oddNumber.length; i++)
        if(i % 2 !== 0) 
            yield i;   
}      

// Spread operator to loop this back out to an array
console.log([...oddNumberZ()])
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. Your first code cleared my doubt. I wrote similar code in python and I had a return value which I can always use. I wanted to know if there is a way I could write same code without using the array method of .push in javascript.

Comment: @Kingsley you could use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method on the `oddNumber` array to filter out any even number and return the filtered array.

Comment: simply do `for(let i = 1; i < oddNumber.length; i+=2) results.push(i)` do the same

Comment: @Kingsley yes, the easiest way is `oddNumber.filter(i => i % 2 !== 0)`

Comment: nope this is `oddNumber.filter((n,i) => i % 2 !== 0)`

Comment: or   `oddNumber.filter((_,i) => (i & 1))`

Comment: @MisterJojo ahh, well spotted, but then we also need a map from value to index